# Split Paragraphs and Save Ranges in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am trying to split paragraphs into an array of components using the code I have typed below. I am having trouble with the Ranges element though. My problem is that if the user types a string multiple times it returns the first times range and not the one I am wanting.

**Example:**
Paragraph 1: Banana
Paragraph 2: Apple
Paragraph 3: Banana

Both Paragraph 1 and 3 will have Paragraph 1's range. What is a smarter way of going about this to fix this problem?

```
lazy var models: [ParagraphModel] = []

struct ParagraphModel {
    let text: String
    let range: Range<String.Index>
}

func getParagraphs(){
  let components = textView.text.components(separatedBy: "\n")

  let models = components.compactMap { component -> ParagraphModel? in
    if let range = textView.text.range(of: component) {
        return ParagraphModel(text: component, range: range)
    }
    return nil
  }
 self.models = models
}
```

Updated Code from @Rob:

```
func getParagraphModel() {
    guard let text = noteContents.text else { return }

    var currentModels: [ParagraphModel] = []
    text.enumerateSubstrings(in: text.startIndex..., options: .byParagraphs) { substring, range, _, stop in
        if  let substring = substring, !substring.isEmpty,
            let textRange = self.noteContents.text.range(of: substring)
        {
            currentModels.append(ParagraphModel(text: substring, range: textRange))
        }
    }
    self.models = currentModels
}
```

When typing the example Text the printout to the console is:

`[Project.ViewController.ParagraphModel(text: "Banana", range: Range(Swift.String.Index(_rawBits: 0)..<Swift.String.Index(_rawBits: 393216))), Project.ViewController.ParagraphModel(text: "Apple", range: Range(Swift.String.Index(_rawBits: 458752)..<Swift.String.Index(_rawBits: 786432))), Project.ViewController.ParagraphModel(text: "Banana", range: Range(Swift.String.Index(_rawBits: 0)..<Swift.String.Index(_rawBits: 393216)))]`

Comment: @LeoDabus Sorry, updated now. I just use it to update a local variable named 'models'.

Comment: @LeoDabus Yep, updated 

Comment: I don’t understand this question. You tell us that `range` in your `ParagraphModel` is a `Range<String.Index>`, but your code is telling us that it is a `UITextRange`. Which is it?

Comment: @Rob I am trying to use Range<String.Index> because that seems easiest, is this what is producing the error? That I am not using UITextRange?

Comment: @Rob The error is that in the example paragraphs I get the same range for paragraph 1 as paragraph 3. I need them to be different. The code that I am trying isn't fixing this problem on my end. Paragraph 1 & 3 display Paragraph 1's range.

Comment: @LeoDabus Yep, exactly! Does `enumerateSubstrings` circumvent this or not?

Comment: Yes, `enumerateSubstrings` will enumerate the paragraphs and their respective ranges in the broader string. It avoids problems resulting from searching from the start of the string every time. It’s also a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code snippet is that you’re always going to find the first occurrence of the target string. So, when it’s searching for the third paragraph, “Banana”, it’s going to find the first occurrence of that string.

I would suggest `text.enumerateSubstrings(in:options:_:)` to get the ranges of the paragraphs within `text`. This will enumerate the substrings and their respective ranges, which avoids you searching for the text yourself, avoiding problems that can arise if the same string appears multiple times.

Thus:

```
func getParagraphs() {
    guard let textView = textView, let text = textView.text else { return }

    models = []
    text.enumerateSubstrings(in: text.startIndex..., options: .byParagraphs) { substring, range, _, _ in
        guard let substring = substring, !substring.isEmpty else {
            return
        }

        self.models.append(ParagraphModel(text: substring, range: range))
    }
}
```

That produces:

```
[
    MyApp.ParagraphModel(text: "Paragraph 1: Banana", range: Range(Swift.String.Index(_rawBits: 0)..<Swift.String.Index(_rawBits: 1245184))),
    MyApp.ParagraphModel(text: "Paragraph 2: Apple", range: Range(Swift.String.Index(_rawBits: 1376256)..<Swift.String.Index(_rawBits: 2555904))),
    MyApp.ParagraphModel(text: "Paragraph 3: Banana", range: Range(Swift.String.Index(_rawBits: 2686976)..<Swift.String.Index(_rawBits: 3932160)))
]
```

Or, if `range` in `ParagraphModel` was a `UITextRange`, you’d do:

```
func getParagraphs() {
    guard let textView = textView, let text = textView.text else { return }

    models = []
    text.enumerateSubstrings(in: text.startIndex..., options: .byParagraphs) { substring, range, _, stop in
        let nsRange = NSRange(range, in: text)

        if  let substring = substring,
            !substring.isEmpty,
            let start = textView.position(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, offset: nsRange.location),
            let end = textView.position(from: start, offset: nsRange.length),
            let textRange = self.textView.textRange(from: start, to: end)
        {
            self.models.append(ParagraphModel(text: substring, range: textRange))
        }
    }
}
```

Producing:

```
[
    MyApp.ParagraphModel(text: "Paragraph 1: Banana", range: <_UITextKitTextRange: 0x6000037983e0> (0, 19)F),
    MyApp.ParagraphModel(text: "Paragraph 2: Apple", range: <_UITextKitTextRange: 0x600003798260> (21, 18)F),
    MyApp.ParagraphModel(text: "Paragraph 3: Banana", range: <_UITextKitTextRange: 0x600003799f20> (41, 19)F)
]
```

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for that. I just tried your code and it is still producing the wrong range error...What should I do?

Comment: Is the `range` in your `ParagraphModel` _really_ a `Range<String.Index>`? Your code suggests that it must be a `UITextRange`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I was trying 2 different options to get this to work. It seems Range<String.Index> is easier but really it doesn't matter as long as I am getting unique range values...

Comment: @mink23 - This code, like Leo’s, does give us unique range values. You need to edit your question and clarify precisely what the problem is.

Comment: @Rob I have updated with the code I now have and the printout to the console which shows the same range values for paragraph 3 as paragraph 1.

Comment: Amazing @Rob just so I can learn, what changed to now allow this to work?